# Unexpected case sensitivty

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a noob running elastic search 1.5.9. I want to pull out all of the documents that have the field "PERSON" set to "Johnson." (Note the mixed casing). If I manually look at elastic search [head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head), I can see a document with exactly those attributes.

The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html) explain that I should construct a filter query to pull out this document. But when I do so, I get some unexpected behavior.

This works. It returns exactly one document w/ Person = "Johnson", as expected

```
query = {"filter": {"term" : { "PERSON" : "johnson" }}}
```

But this does not work

```
query = {"filter": {"term" : { "PERSON" : "Johnson" }}}
```

If you look closely, you'll see that the good query is lowercase but the bad query is mixed case -- even though the PERSON field is set to "Johnson".

Adding to the weirdness, I am lower casing everything that goes into the `full_text` field: `"_source": { "full_text": "all lower case"` So the full text includes `johnson` -- which I would think would be totally independent from the PERSON field.

What's going on? How do I do a mixed case search on the PERSON field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term query wont analyze your search text. 
This means you need to analyzed and provide the query in token format for term query to actually work.
Use [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) instead , things will work like magic.

So when a string like below goes to Elasticsearch , its tokenized ( or rather analyzed) and stored

```
"Green Apple" -> ( "green" , "apple")
```

This is the default behavior of analysis.
Now when you search using term query , the analysis wont happen.
Which means for the word Apple , it searches for the token Apple with case preserved. And hence fails.

For match query , it does do the analysis. Which means if you search with Apple , it converts it to apple and then does the search. Which give good matches.

You can learn more on analysis [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html).

Comment: that sounds helpful, but can you elaborate. What does "analyze" and "token format" mean. Also, what is the syntax for the match query?

Comment: "So when a string like below goes to Elasticsearch" do you mean a string being indexed? or a query string?

Comment: Indexed . Ideally the analysis has to happen both while indexing and searching.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show the syntax of a match query. I'm having trouble {"match" : { "message" : "this is a test"}} gives --> Parse Failure [No parser for element [match]]];   https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: { "query" : { "match" : { "message" : "this is a test"}} }